# Protractor won't click items on drop-down (Angular Material 2)

Tags: angular, protractor

Hi I have a problem with my protractor test case. I have a text field on a web application. I want to click in the field and then click on the first element on the drop-down list that appears. The problem is that protractor won't click on any item on the list.

My stack is: protractor, cucumber and the tested application is on Angular2.

My code looks like this:

```
this.When(/^I click first element in "([^"]*)"$/, function (name) {
    return element(pageCtx.elements[name].boxSelector).all(pageCtx.elements[name].elementSelector)
        .first()
        .click();
});
```

It looks as if the function doesn't go in the drop-down list and therefore doesn't click on any items from it.
I did read about such issues on the Internet e.g. [this article](https://thecattlecrew.net/2015/03/05/automated-ui-tests-for-an-angularjs-material-select-item-with-protractor/). Probably I should do some thing with wait, and I tied but it seems to me that it doesn't change anything. Maybe I put the waits in wrong places.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first click the dropdown and then click the first element in the list. You will likely want to use async/await. For example:

```
this.When(/^I click first element in "([^"]*)"$/, async function (name)
   {
     await element(pageCtx.elements[name].boxSelector).click();
     await element.all(pageCtx.elements[name].elementSelector)
            .first()
            .click();
    });
```